# How to post jquery to current file

Tags: php, jquery

Below is a fragment of code i'm working on, saved in index.php:

```
$("#login").click(function(){   
  username=$("#name").val();
  password=$("#word").val();
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "login.php",
data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
```

For some reason I want the destination url to be the same as the current file(say index.php)and not login.php, how do  I do this? And if i place the php script in index.php, it just runs even when the form has not been submitted, if I place a condition like `if(isset($_POST['name']))` on it, it doesn't work again with jquery. However, I'll like a fallback when js is disabled in
the browser.

Comment: Just that simple: `url: "",` :-)

Comment: In that case, the php script just runs without clicking submit

Comment: what??? so you want to press submit button?? than replace `action` in your `<form ...>` and there is no difference between your code and my , just `url` so it couldn't impact the flow and behavior

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
url : location.href
```

we can set url to current page